# Where should log4j.properties be put in a maven project? src/main/resources not working

Tags: java, maven, selenium, logging, log4j

Where should I place my log4j.properties file if I don't user the PropertyConfigurator class and Where should I place my log4j.properties file when I want to use the PropertyConfigurator class?

When I don't use the PropertyConfigurator, `No Appenders could be found for logger (logger1)` `Please initialize the log4j system properly` and 1 other warnings are displayed

When I use the PropertyConfigurator, My code is unable to find my log4j.properties file when I include `PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties")` in my code FileNotFound exception is being displayed.

I googled this issue, but despite doing all the proposed solutions I can't still fix it.

Here is the screenshot of my **MAVEN** project structure

[image: Maven Project Structure]

I manually added the source folder `src/main/resources` in my project and put my log4j.properties file there but it is still not working.

Here is my code

```
package Maven.Log4JTest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Test 
{

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Logger1");

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    log.info("Text Message");
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried `PropertyConfigurator.configure("classpath*:log4j.properties")` ?

Comment: I tried this one and it still has the same error being displayed